# SQL Server 2008 Simple Forecasting

Tags: sql, sql-server, regression, forecasting, trend

I'm creating the following output, and I am looking for a simple way to forecast the NULL values, based on previous months results.
I want to say something like - If the value is NULL calculate the average increase of the past 4 months and apply it to that months numbers.

Is there any way I can do that in SQL please?   Thanks!

`Year month  N30      N3        N6     N12 
2013    1   £23.62  £43.70  £68.96  £104.67
2013    2   £26.13  £50.05  £84.58  £153.97
2013    3   £21.39  £41.16  £62.07  £97.59
2013    4   £21.88  £43.62  £62.66  £94.08
2013    5   £19.06  £31.97  £51.56  £78.86
2013    6   £24.88  £60.32  £79.72  £112.66
2013    7   £16.36  £34.64  £59.30  £85.83
2013    8   £18.98  £36.75  £52.99  £76.60
2013    9   £15.96  £33.70  £57.15  £98.41
2013    10  £15.44  £34.07  £51.69  £75.03
2013    11  £16.88  £38.23  £58.21  £93.72
2013    12  £9.61   £27.78  £46.04  £76.72
2014    1   £16.39  £34.63  £50.47  £87.18
2014    2   £7.59   £26.34  £43.65  NULL
2014    3   £7.22   £21.90  £41.99  NULL
2014    4   £6.50   £22.57  £46.98  NULL
2014    5   £2.80   £23.26  £43.24  NULL
2014    6   £4.96   £27.18  £49.08  NULL
2014    7   £10.06  £35.43  £71.86  NULL
2014    8   £7.53   £31.20  NULL    NULL
2014    9   £10.60  £29.21  NULL    NULL
2014    10  £2.19   £23.38  NULL    NULL
2014    11  £7.82   NULL    NULL    NULL`

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Not much. I am a bit stuck. I currently take it on excel and do the calculations there. Ideally though I would like to create a report, so users can see the full output (as above with the forecasted values) for any set of parameters chosen.